# upload multiple images - php

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, how to make that code support multiple image upload?

I have here 3 button and every one of them can upload single image. I need to make it support multiple upload image. Thank you.

This is all code:

```html
  <?php
class Products extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
            redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }else{
            $user=$_SESSION['user'][0];
            if($user->perm==USER){
                redirect('admin/denied');
            }
        }
        $this->load->model('product_model');
        $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|JPG|JPEG|GIF|PNG';
        $config['max_size']    = '2000';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->load->helper('Ultils');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="help-inline msg-error" generated="true">', '</span>');
    }

    function index(){
        $page     = $this->input->get('page') ? $this->input->get('page') : 0;
        $per_page = $this->input->get('per_page') ? $this->input->get('per_page') : 10;
        $order    = $this->input->get('order') ? $this->input->get('order') : 'DESC';
        $config['base_url']= base_url() . 'index.php/admin/products?order='.$order;
        $config['per_page']=$per_page;
        $data['msg_label']=$this->config->item('msg_label');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->product_model->total(array(), array());
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['list'] = $this->product_model->get("*,products.id as id,products.activated as activated", array(),array(),$page, $per_page, array('products.id' => 'DESC'));
        $data['page_link'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->template->write_view('content','backends/products/index',array('data'=>$data));
        $this->template->render();
    }

    public function create(){
        $error=null;
        $images=array();
        $image_path=null;
        $insert_id =0;
        $thumb=null;
        if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
            if(isset($_POST['title'])){
                $user=$_SESSION['user'][0];
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('title','title', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[100]|xss_clean');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'price', 'trim|numeric|xss_clean');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('aim', 'aim', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'content', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[2000]|xss_clean');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('provinces', 'provinces', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('cities', 'cities', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('categories', 'categories', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

                if($this->form_validation->run()!=false){
                    $data['title']=preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', "", $this->input->post('title'));
                    $data['price']=$this->input->post('price');
                    $data['aim']=$this->input->post('aim');
                    $data['content']=preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', "", htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('content')));
                    $data['county_id']=$this->input->post('provinces');
                    $data['categories_id']=$this->input->post('categories');
                    $data['user_id']=$user->id;
                    $data['cities_id']=$this->input->post('cities');
                    $insert_id = $this->product_model->insert($data);
                    $allowed =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg');
                    $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
                    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    if(in_array($ext,$allowed)) {
                        $upload_result=self::upload();
                        if($upload_result!=null){
                            $image_path=$upload_result;
                            array_push($images, $upload_result);
                            $this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'image', 'callback_upload');
                        }else{
                            $error['error_upload_file']="Can not upload file, please check again";
                        }
                    }else{
                        $error['eror_upload_file']="Your upload file contains invalid allow upload file type";
                    }

                    $filename = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
                    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    if(in_array($ext,$allowed)) {
                        $upload_result=self::upload1();
                        if($upload_result!=null){
                            $image_path=$upload_result;
                            array_push($images, $upload_result);
                            $this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'image', 'callback_upload');
                        }else{
                            $error['error_upload_file_1']="Can not upload file, please check again";
                        }
                    }else{
                        $error['eror_upload_file_1']="Your upload file contains invalid allow upload file type";
                    }

                    $filename = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
                    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    if(in_array($ext,$allowed)) {
                        $upload_result=self::upload2();
                        if($upload_result!=null){
                            $image_path=$upload_result;
                            array_push($images, $upload_result);
                            $this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'image', 'callback_upload');
                        }else{
                            $error['error_upload_file_2']="Can not upload file, please check again";
                        }
                    }else{
                        $error['eror_upload_file_2']="Your upload file contains invalid allow upload file type";
                    }

                    if($insert_id!=0){
                        if($image_path!=null){
                            $config=array(
                            "source_image" => 'uploads/'.$image_path, //get original image
                            "new_image" =>  "uploads/thumbs", //save as new image //need to create thumbs first
                            "maintain_ratio" => true,
                            "width" => 200,
                            "height" => 200
                            );
                            $this->load->library('image_lib',$config);
                            $this->image_lib->resize();
                            $image_path= 'uploads/thumbs/'.$image_path;
                            $this->product_model->update(array('image_path'=>$image_path), array('id'=>$insert_id));
                            $this->load->model('images_model');
                            for ($i=0; $i < count($images); $i++) {
                                $this->images_model->insert(array('path'=>'uploads/'.$images[$i],'product_id'=>$insert_id));
                            }
                        }
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_ok',$this->lang->line('add_successfully'));
                        redirect('admin/products/create');
                    }
                }
            }
            ;    }else{
                redirect('admin/dashboard');
            }
            $this->load->model('county_model');
            $data['provinces']=$this->county_model->get();
            $this->load->model('categories_model');
            $data['categories']=$this->categories_model->get();
            $this->template->write_view('content','backends/products/add',array('data'=>$data,'error'=>$error));
            $this->template->render();
        }

        public function upload(){
            if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
                $filename=$_FILES['image']['name'];
                $_FILES['image']['name']=rename_upload_file($filename);
            }
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('image'))
            {
                return $_FILES['image']['name'];
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public function upload1(){
            if(isset($_FILES['image1'])){
                $filename=$_FILES['image1']['name'];
                $_FILES['image1']['name']=rename_upload_file($filename);
            }
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('image1'))
            {
                return $_FILES['image1']['name'];
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public function upload2(){
            if(isset($_FILES['image2'])){
                $filename=$_FILES['image2']['name'];
                $_FILES['image2']['name']=rename_upload_file($filename);
            }
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('image2'))
            {
                return $_FILES['image2']['name'];
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public function check_username_exist_add($name){
            $data=$this->product_model->get_by_exact_name($name, 0, 1);
            if ($data!=null)
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('check_username_exist_add', 'This name has exist');
                return FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }

        public function check_username_exist_edit(){
            $id=$this->input->post('id');
            $name=$this->input->post('name');
            $data=$this->product_model->get_by_name_and_diff_id($id,$name);
            if($data!=null) {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('check_username_exist_edit', 'This name has exist');
                return FALSE;
            } else {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }

        public function edit_get(){
            if(isset($_GET['id'])){
                $id=$this->input->get('id');
                $data=parent::getDataView();
                $data['obj']=$this->product_model->get_by_id($id);
                $this->blade->render('backends/products/edit',array('data'=>$data));
            }
        }

        public function edit_post(){
            if(isset($_POST['id'])){
                $id=$_POST['id'];
                $name=$_POST['name'];
                $data=parent::getDataView();
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','name', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[60]|xss_clean|callback_check_username_exist_edit');
                if($this->form_validation->run()){
                    $this->product_model->update(array('name'=>$name),array('id'=>$id));
                }
                $data['obj']=$this->product_model->get_by_id($id);
                $this->blade->render('backends/products/edit',array('data'=>$data));
            }
        }

        public function delete(){
            if(isset($_GET['id'])){
                $id=$this->input->get('id');
                $product=$this->product_model->get_by_id($id);
                if($product!=null){
                    $this->load->model('images_model');
                    $images=$this->images_model->get_by_product_id($id);
                    foreach ($images as $r) {
                        try {
                            unlink($r->path);
                            $this->images_model->remove_by_id($r->id);
                        } catch (Exception $e) {

                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        unlink($product[0]->image_path);
                    } catch (Exception $e) {

                    }
                }
                $this->product_model->remove_by_id($id);

                redirect('admin/products');
            }
        }

        public function activate(){
            if(isset($_GET['id'])){
                $id=$this->input->get('id');
                echo $id;
                $this->product_model->update(array('activated'=>1),array('id'=>$id));
            }
            redirect('admin/products');
        }

        public function lock(){
            if(isset($_GET['id'])){
                $id=$this->input->get('id');
                $this->product_model->update(array('activated'=>0),array('id'=>$id));
            }
            redirect('admin/products');
        }

        public function search(){
            if(isset($_GET['query'])){
                $query=$this->input->get('query');
                $data=parent::getDataView();
                $page     = $this->input->get('page') ? $this->input->get('page') : 0;
                $per_page = $this->input->get('per_page') ? $this->input->get('per_page') : 10;
                $order    = $this->input->get('order') ? $this->input->get('order') : 'DESC';
                $config['total_rows'] = $this->product_model->total(array(), array('title'=>$query));
                $config['base_url']= base_url() . 'index.php/admin/products/search?order='.$order.'&query='.$query;
                $config['per_page']=$per_page;
                $data['msg_label']=$this->config->item('msg_label');
                $this->pagination->initialize($config);
                $data['list'] = $this->product_model->get_by_name($query,$page,$per_page);
                $data['page_link'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
                $data['search_title']='Result search for "'.$query.'"';
                $this->template->write_view('content','backends/products/index',array('data'=>$data));
                $this->template->render();
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: can you show us your html form?

Answer (score 1):

Allow your HTML file input to select many files like `<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple>` and then loop through the same $_FILES var. Also, don't forget to add the `<form>` enctype attribute like `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

```
$image_files = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
foreach($image_files as $key=>$value){
    // write some code to process the information
    // this will loop through all the images, no matter how many, so the same code inside these curly braces will be applied to each file/image/whatever.
}
```